# Custom Node constants

Tags: javascript, node.js

In Node JS there is a __dirname constant.

Can I define my own constants in the same form?

eg:

__root

or

__myCrazyConstant

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a variable with any name you want, no matter how many underscores it contains.

You can create a constant with the `const` keyword:

```
const myContsant = 42;
myConstant = 0;
console.log(myConstant); // 42
```